# How to dismiss pop over view in content view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

see the screen shot is clear to understand what I mean
[image]
you can see I add a navigationItem in my pop view

I wish I can dismiss the pop view

But it seems only tab the cell under the pop view

The pop view will dismiss,I try to add this method

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

It only remove the table view , the pop view frame is still there ,only without the content view

Any reply will be helpful : )

Thanks

Webber

/******EDIT******/
I use [WEPopoverView](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover) into my project

And this is the code I create the pop view when I select the table view

```
if (indexPath.row==2) {
DaysOfWeek *popView = [[DaysOfWeek alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navPopView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popView];
    if (self.popoverController) {
       [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
       self.popoverController = nil;
}
else {
        self.popoverController = [[[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navPopView] autorelease];
        CGRect frame = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame;
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:frame 
                                                    inView:self.view            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                  animated:YES];
                        }
                    }
```

/******EDIT2******/
I try to add Done button when I create the pop view
here is the code , But it only appear a navigation , no Done button

```
DaysOfWeek *popView = [[DaysOfWeek alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navPopView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popView];
navPopView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(hidePopView)];
```

Comment: How do you create the pop view? Post some code, please, so that we can try and help you...

Comment: I add the code how I create the popview , sorr about I miss that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that simply releasing your `self.popoverController` will do the dismiss properly, including all the superviews.

You can also have a look at the `dealloc` method in `WEPopoverController` to see which views are involved and need to be removed:

```
    [self dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    [contentViewController release];
    [containerViewProperties release];
    [passthroughViews release];
```

Anyway, the only advantage I see is the possibility of calling `dismissPopoverAnimated` with `YES`.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

How can you connect your done button to your controller?

Make your button accessible through a read-only property of `DaysOfWeek`; then in your controller, when you create `DaysOfWeek`, do:

```
 DaysOfWeek *popView = [[DaysOfWeek alloc]init];
 [propView.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fullyDismissPopover) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In fullyDismissPopover, you call release or call the sequence of functions highlighted above (but release would be better, I think).

Comment: if([ApplicationDelegate.aPopover isPopoverVisible])
 {
  [ApplicationDelegate.aPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 }

Comment: The done button is in another view class....how to call the super view controller to dismiss it？

Comment: The popview is not in AppDelegate,In the root view controller(TableView Controller)

Comment: You don't explain how the `UIButton` and the view enclosing it are created, but the way to go is setting the view controller as a target for the click through `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Could you find a way to do that when you create the button?

Comment: I declare the button create in the DaysOfWeek.m

Answer (score 1):

While you add the popup view, set tag to that popupView and then, add them as subview,

then use:

```
for (UIView *tempView in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([tempView tag]==urTag) {
        [tempView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This retrieves all the subviews and then remove only your popupview

Comment: I was using pop view in iphone , so could be some parts are differents,I add my code , hope it help
Still thank you so much

Comment: DaysOfWeek *popView = [[DaysOfWeek alloc]init];
 
 [popView setTag:100];
 
 
 then where do u want to dissmiss this popView then use below for loop and specify that 100 for urTag

Comment: I already add this code in other row in table view section 2 , The problem is iphone view is too small , it will cover the based view...

Comment: no problem and keep login to that chat and stay on there by enable destop notification to get instant help....see http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Answer (score 0):

```
 DaysOfWeek *popView = [[DaysOfWeek alloc]init];
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hidePopView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
popView.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:doneButton] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navPopView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popView];
```

This also can figure out the problem !